# FFMpeg is writing a matplotlib animation with diminishing quality

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, ffmpeg

I am trying to create a bunch of animations that follow the paths National Hockey League teams travel during the current season. Currently, [my animation looks like this](https://gfycat.com/GenerousRichJerboa).

As you can see, the animation begins decently sharp but within 2 seconds the quality bottoms out and everything is grainy.

The relevant code is this:

```
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=len(all_x + 20), 
                              interval=75, repeat=False)
filepath =  map_team + '.mp4'
ani.save(filepath, writer='ffmpeg', fps=30)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I have chosen FFMpeg as my writer because I hope to put about 30 graphics online and the MP4 format keeps each file around 1.5MB. If there's a way to keep the graphics sharp, with low file sizes, and able to be uploaded onto Imgur, I would love to do that with my project.

Thanks.

Comment: The video at gfycat is a webm. So, I guess that's not your ffmpeg output. Can you show the MP4 produced by ffmpeg? And which version of ffmpeg is it?

Comment: Not sure if this is really a matplotlib issue. You can set any parameters to the movie writer, like `writer = matplotlib.animation.FFMpegWriter(fps=100, 
            codec="h264", bitrate=1000000, 
            extra_args=["-preset", "veryslow","-crf","0"]); 
ani.save("mov.mp4", writer=writer)`, see [here](http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FFMpegWriter.html). But usually the preset parameters are good enough.