# Matplotlib animation quality loss

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, ffmpeg, imshow

I'm currently trying to use matplotlib to animate a grid using imshow. However, I am finding a fairly significant quality loss in the animation.

Below is a simple animation that illustrates my issue fairly well. If you look at any particular frame of *imagelist*, you will see that there is no aliasing or gradient between colours. But if I then look at one frame of my animation, that is no longer the case. There is now a 4-5 pixel  gradient between my blocks of colour. Does anyone know how I can get around this compression? The file size of the animation doesn't matter too much, as long as I can get a good quality animation.

```
#Create list of images
image=np.array([[[0,0,0],(0.7,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0.8)]])
imagelist=[]
for i in range(0,100):
    image[0][1][0]=i/100
    imagelist.append(np.copy(image))

#Create figure    
fig = plt.figure()
plt.axis('off')
im = plt.imshow(imagelist[0], vmin=0, vmax=255,interpolation='none');

#Animation
def updatefig(j):
    im.set_array(imagelist[j])
    return [im]
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updatefig, frames=range(len(imagelist)), interval=20, blit=False)

#Save animation
FFMpegWriter = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
mywriter = FFMpegWriter(fps=30, bitrate=5000)
ani.save("test.mp4", writer=mywriter,codec="libx264")
```

Comment: Looks like the same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42588065/ffmpeg-is-writing-a-matplotlib-animation-with-diminishing-quality). At that question I wasn't able to reproduce the issue, same here.

Comment: Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28785118/pixelated-animations-in-matplotlib) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203311/matplotlib-animation-movie-quality-of-movie-decreasing-with-time) seem to be related. One issue is that you should give arguments to the writer instance and not in the save function, but it's not clear if this is the problem here.